# Package IRIS for AWS Lambda - using pip install

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, anaconda, python-3.7, amazon-efs

How can packages installed via Conda to be made available to AWS Lambda. This package is of size greater than 500MB post compression. May dependencies are build using the underlying C files. Also this package is nearly impossible to compile from code ( for using pip install  -target <target_dir> ) using the equivalent pip install method.

The method followed,

1. install iris in miniconda --> conda install -n irispy37 -c conda-forge iris
2. Extract packages using conda pack (https://github.com/conda/conda-pack)
3. Extracted the conda pack libraries to efs and mounted same to Lambda

I set up AWS EFS and configured to be accessible by AWS Lambda. But Lambda is failing to import iris.

Lambda is not picking this up.

Comment: Have you tried setting `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: Yes - Set PYTHONPATH - didnt work. Also set the path brutally using sys.path.append("/mnt/lambda/lib"). Both the approaches were futile.